# iphone sqlite issue

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, objective-c-runtime

I tried importing db in my Supporting files folder and connected to db using:

```
NSString *sqliteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”person” ofType:@”sqlite”];
if(sqlite3_open([sqliteDb UTF8String], & database)!=SQLITE_OK)
```

I tried inserting values through code which got inserted but when I quit the program and check the db that values are not present. I don't know what's going wrong here.

Comment: Have you attached source database with your application?

Comment: yeah.. i have attached..

Comment: dont know sqllite in ios, but i think you forgot to commit the changes  to the database
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application#Implementing_the_Code_to_Save_Data_to_the_SQLite_Database

Comment: i did that.. using finalize_statement in iOS... I have read that we have to first copy the db in Documents folder to edit... But, I could not find the code or any help..

Comment: first reset your simulater and again add your database do not take referance. and after that use iApple code(below). in the place of .rsd use your data base extension.it will be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Now copy that database to any local place which will be your data storage of the application. The code given below will do the same.

```
    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *docDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"person.rsd"] retain];    
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL success = [fm fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(success) return;
    NSString *dbPathFromApp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent :@"person.rsd"];
    [fm copyItemAtPath:dbPathFromApp toPath:dbPath error:nil];
```

After that, execute your query and you will get inserted data in your application simulator folder.

Answer (score 1):

Files in the bundle are read-only. You can not edit them. You need to copy that database to the app's cache, document or temp directory to perform operations.

Answer (score 0):

First copy your person.sqlite db into application's document directory and then open that db for operations.